# Creator Design tab is displaying nothing

Tags: c++, qt, qml

The window doesn't show up for some reason, any reason why?

[image: Thanks for the help.]

Comment: could you fix this? I use Qt creator 5.14.0 in ubuntu and I don't have a problem but as I install Qt5.15.2 in windows I have your problem too. The design doesn't show anything.